# How to integrate google AdSense in NextJS project?

Tags: testing, next.js, ads, adsense, adsense-api

Integrate google AdSense in NextJS project?

I tried several way which gives on internet blog but I was stuck each method. and I tried AdSense at dummy site but It couldn't work in my case

[image: Dummy site testing]

Here I have several Question regarding Google AdSense:

- Is there any dynamic traffic required to integrate ads at NextJS app ?
- If there is any traffic required then how we can start at locally or via live third party hosting or using github CD/CI ?
- How we can set layout of google ads layout?

How to integrate Next App to AdSense?
How to test google AdSense ads in my NextJS App?

Answer (score 0):

The message itself says that AdSense will not show ads on screens that they found are low-value content or under development.

Apply for Adsense, only when your site is **fully functional** and has content or tools which is **helpful** for others.